# What would be some observable differences between universes with different global curvatures?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, universe, curvature

Title says it all. I'm just curious to hear any wacky consequences.
Assume I know little on the topic--because that's true.

Edit:
I am talking about global observable universe curvature, as discussed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shape_of_the_universe#Curvature).
Primarily, I'm interested in hearing about interesting observable differences such as behavior of light, gravity, dynamics of cosmic objects, etc.

Comment: What does "look like" mean?  What is the answer to "What does a sphere look like?"

Answer (score 3):

If it had positive curvature, very distant galaxies would have a larger apparent diameter, and if the universe had negative curvature then distant galaxies would have a smaller apparent diameter. I think there are theories that include other more subtle differences, but apparent galaxy size is the obvious one, IMO.

Comment: +1 that's a better answer than mine

Comment: precise answer!

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm getting at. Fascinating stuff.

Comment: Actually, after thinking about it, its not so much that galaxies would appear larger, but that each point of light would appear larger, so galaxies would be out of focus. in fact, it seems this focus issue would be an extremely precise way of telling that the universe is flat.

Answer (score -1):

But *it is not flat*. Gravity is understood as curvature in spacetime; if you want to see the light-warping effect of gravitational lensing; [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z0QtYV81aTA) is a good video.

Comment: The question was about global curvature.

Comment: Please point out to me which part of the question indicates that?

Comment: It's obvious. If people talk about the curvature of the universe, they mean the global curvature (everything else would be nonsense !).

Comment: The question was about the universe being not-flat. I don't know about you, but I don't call a grass field with pits and bumps "flat". Not even if it turns out to be flat "on average".

Comment: That's not the Point. global flatness isn't defined like that. It depends on the hubble Parameter etc....

Comment: "Assume I know little on the topic--because that's true." <- I'm not sure that your assertions about what the asker meant apply if they're premised on having knowledge about the technical definition of global flatness or the hubble parameter, etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47598/discussion-between-vaesper-and-physics-guy).

Comment: Yes, I meant global, not local curvature.